# Read multiple file, Extract certain column, Remove certain row, and write into multiple new files

Tags: r, loops, csv, subset

I have thousands of files with the extension .txt, with spaces ("") as separators in a common folder. I need to:

1. Extract certain columns. I need to remove the last column and only select column 1,2,3 and 7 for example. I already write this code with loop:

```
    # Setting working directory
    workingdirectory <- "D:/FolderContainsThousandsFile"
    setwd(workingdirectory)

    # Listing the files in the folder with .txt extension
    FilesList <- list.files(workingdirectory, pattern = ".txt$")
    numberFiles <- length(FilesList)

    # Looping for all files
    for(f in 1:numberFiles){
    # read the file into tables
    FilterFile <- FilesList [f] %>% read.csv(sep = "", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% dplyr::select(-ncol(.)) # remove the last column
```

2. Remove the certain row. The file contains daily weather data for several years, then I need to remove every data on 29th February with this code:

```
    # Remove the 29th day in February
    columnNames <- c("year", "month", "day", "weather")
    FilterFile <- FilterFile %>% rename_at(c(1,2,3,7), ~columnNames) # renaming columns to indicate the column to be taken
    FilterFile <- FilterFile %>% filter(month != 2 | day != 29)
```

3. Last, I need to export the result from point 1) and 2) to be a unique .txt file from all files, with the name of the new file according to the original file (example: `before_file1.txt` into `after_file1.txt`) for each file.

Am i doing the right thing? Please help if you know each of the steps to do that.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
columnNames <- c("year", "month", "day", "weather")
FilesList <- list.files(workingdirectory, pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE)


purrr::map(FilesList, ~{
     .x %>%
       #Read csv file
       read.csv(sep = "", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
       #Remove Last column
       select(-ncol(.)) %>%
       #Rename at particular position with columnNames
       rename_at(c(1,2,3,7), ~columnNames) %>%
       #Remove 29th Februaury
       filter(month != 2 & day != 29) %>%
       #Write the data back
       write.csv(paste0('after', basename(.x)), row.names = FALSE)
})
```

Unless you have a very strong reason to write the data to a text file, I would suggest writing the data in csv instead.

Comment: Thank you for your effort.

I have tried this method. But it doesn't work. 
what command should I put in the "x" on purrr::map(FilesList, ~{.x %>% and basename(x)) to referring each file name?

Comment: @SidiqPambudi Can you try that again, the last line should be `.x` in `basename`. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: The result is:
Error in basename(.x) : object '.x' not found

do I miss put certain command?

Comment: and now I missed a pipe after `filter` and `rename_at`. Sorry about that, updated the answer again.

Comment: Pardon me. There is still an error, Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'renamecol' not found

Comment: That is weird, I am not using `renamecol` anywhere in my answer. Can you recheck my answer and make sure you use the variables that are present. Perhaps, you mean to use `columnNames` ?

Comment: Sorry my fault, I was changing your script. Now i already return to your script, it works. 
Thank you for your help